# RavenDB: Returning objects with null values for properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ravendb

I'm using Raven in ASP.NET MVC as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = Strings.Workflows;
    ViewBag.AddNewText = Strings.Add_new;

    IEnumerable<WorkflowIndexViewModel> model;
    using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        model = session.Query<Workflow>()
            .Select(w => new WorkflowIndexViewModel { WorkflowId = w.Id, WorkflowName = w.Name })
            .ToArray();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

The weird thing is that the `model` object has one value in (as I'd expect because I know I have one `Workflow` document in my database), but both `WorkflowId` and `WorkfloName` properties on it are `null`. Why is this? Is there a problem with my projection?

I have tried moving the `ToArray()` call to **before** the `Select()`, and that works just fine:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = Strings.Workflows;
    ViewBag.AddNewText = Strings.Add_new;

    IEnumerable<WorkflowIndexViewModel> model;
    using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        model = session.Query<Workflow>()
            .ToArray()
            .Select(w => new WorkflowIndexViewModel { WorkflowId = w.Id, WorkflowName = w.Name });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: When you run the query (the one not working) what does the raw http request look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the names of your properties in the view model to the same as the Workflow class it will work.

```
model = session.Query<Workflow>()
        .Select(w => new WorkflowIndexViewModel { Id = w.Id, Name = w.Name })
        .ToArray();
```

But that is just a workaround to what seems to be a bug or a limitation.

Comment: Fixed in unstable. But you already know that http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/10d682d8a12b8e76 ;)